# Can Jekyll serve content based on a URL parameter?

Tags: wordpress, jekyll, github-pages

I'm migrating a blog from WordPress to GitHub pages. In the logs for my site, I've noticed that there are many requests like this:

```
GET /wp/?feed=atom
```

This 301 redirects to the ATOM feed for the site.

I'd planned to use `httrack` to scrape my site and migrate all the static content. But this presents a problem. Is there any way to replicate the `/wp/?foo=bar` redirects using Jekyll?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Jekyll redirect_from plugin](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-redirect-from) which is one of the rare plugin that can be used on github pages.

The only problem is that `yoursite.github.io/wp/?foo=bar` from the server point of view is `yoursite.github.io/wp/index.php?foo=bar`. So, any `?foo=bar` is resolved to the same file.

I you have only your xml feed to redirect, this does the trick :

```
---
layout: null
redirect_from:
  - /wp/
---
content ...
```

If you have multiple files to redirect, you will have to switch to a javascript solution from a `wp/index.html` file.

Comment: Unfortunately there's a mix of requests for pages and feeds going through that URL. Many of the requests come from feed readers, which won't resolve JavaScript redirects. One thought is to use the redirect-from plugin to redirect all these requests through a tiny Heroku app with custom redirect logic that redirects back to the GitHub pages site. A problem there is that `/wp/` is a valid URL on its own.

Comment: Ugh, looks like Jekyll redirect_from just [uses JS redirects](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-redirect-from/issues/49), not 301 or 302s.

Comment: I wound up using a somewhat crappy solution: a [big list of JavaScript redirects](https://github.com/danvk/danvk.github.io/commit/f99fa0d6ef808a2ba468587d3f7eab800d448f1e). This is lousy for feed readers and other bots, but I literally see no other way.