# Jekyll redirects on Github pages migrated from wordpress blog with ?page_id=

Tags: redirect, jekyll, github-pages

I followed the jekyll-redirect-from method described [here](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-redirect-from).

if I add

`redirect-from: /old_about or /old_about/`

it works just fine. But if I have a link like :

`redirect-from: /?page_id=654`

like when migrating an (old) wordpress blog, the redirect does not work anymore.

It looks like jekyll-redirect-from creates a page on the site stucture named ?page_id=654 with the redirect code inside. But that page does not load: browsers take that as a GET element, not a page.

Any idea how to still use redirects?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer which isn't really one : there is an [open issue](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-redirect-from/issues/28) on jekyll-redirect-from on github and [another post from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26374707/can-jekyll-serve-content-based-on-a-url-parameter) with details.